# Android: How to run cordova?

Tags: android, windows, cordova, adb

i have a android 10, i can run cordova using a laptop but on another laptop i can run it, said the following msj when i rui it on cmd (windows)

```html
C:\Users\ebsig\Dropbox\Trabajo\HTML PRUEBAS\pruebas_cordova\pruebas2\pruebas2>cordova run
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\ebsig\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ebsig\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\ebsig\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9s
40 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 39 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        C:\Users\ebsig\Dropbox\Trabajo\HTML PRUEBAS\pruebas_cordova\pruebas2\pruebas2\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\ebsig\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ebsig\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\ebsig\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Deploying to device L2NPH19C05XXXXXXX
Using apk: C:\Users\ebsig\Dropbox\Trabajo\HTML PRUEBAS\pruebas_cordova\pruebas2\pruebas2\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
Package name: io.cordova.hellocordova
Command failed with exit code 1: adb -s L2NPH19C05XXXXXX install -r C:\Users\ebsig\Dropbox\Trabajo\HTML PRUEBAS\pruebas_cordova\pruebas2\pruebas2\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
adb: failed to install C:\Users\ebsig\Dropbox\Trabajo\HTML PRUEBAS\pruebas_cordova\pruebas2\pruebas2\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package io.cordova.hellocordova signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
Performing Streamed Install
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

The file, having it created on another computer and having installed it on my mobile phone, was signed in a different way, so when trying to install it from the new computer it did not leave me with the signature that the previously installed application had.

solution: delete the app on the device,
and create it (from the new computer "cordova run") again from 0 with the clean device.